# How to upload the stub.jar generated by spring cloud contract

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I've been using Spring Cloud Contract to test the Producer Side. And now, I wanted to upload the stub.jar file to nexus, so my colleague could write some integration test against my producer. And I found the Spring Documentation hard to follow.

```
    <!-- First disable the default jar setup in the properties section-->
    <!-- we don't want the verifier to do a jar for us --> 
    <spring.cloud.contract.verifier.skip>true</spring.cloud.contract.verifier.skip> 

<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
<id>stubs</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**com/example/model/*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**com/example/model/*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/snippets/stubs</directory>
        <outputDirectory>META-INF/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/mappings</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources/contracts</directory>
        <outputDirectory>META-INF/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/contracts</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

1. After I add the "skip" line to the pom, I found that stubs json never get generated.
2. I'm using Spring Cloud Contract 1.2.4, and I think there is only "stub" folder in the target, not a "snippets/stubs".
3. What files are required in the stub.jar for the Stub Runner to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been using Spring Cloud Contract to test the Producer Side. And now, I wanted to upload the stub.jar file to nexus, so my colleague could write some integration test against my producer.

If you use the DSL there's nothing you need to do. Just do `./mvnw deploy` and we will generate the fat jar and the stubs jar.

> And I found the Spring Documentation hard to follow.

That's not really specific is it? What exactly is hard to follow?

> After I add the "skip" line to the pom, I found that stubs json never get generated.

Which `skip` line? If you add `<spring.cloud.contract.verifier.jar.skip>false</spring.cloud.contract.verifier.jar.skip>` then we will disable only JAR creation.

> I'm using Spring Cloud Contract 1.2.4, and I think there is only "stub" folder in the target, not a "snippets/stubs".

Are you even using Rest Docs? Where did you get the snippet from? From here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_publishing_stubs_as_jars ? If you read the text over the snippet you'll see `For both Maven and Gradle, the setup comes ready to work. However, you can customize it if you want to.`. If you follow the step by step section of the documentation we describe the whole, most basic flow. Also there are multiple tutorials out there, including a very thorough one over here http://cloud-samples.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract-samples/workshops.html

> What files are required in the stub.jar for the Stub Runner to run it?

We describe that in the documentation. If you want to use the classpath mapping read this section https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_classpath_scanning . Otherwise, we unpack and go through any WireMock Json file that we can parse.

Here you have a working example of manual creation of stubs jar - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer_with_restdocs . I think you should read the documentation from the beginning and follow the tutorials. Or tell us what exactly is unclear with the documentation that made you feel confused.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin Grzejszczak for your detailed answer.
After go through the references you provided, I understand why I got confused by the doc.
When I simply want to upload a stub to nexus, I go straight to [Section 6](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.2.4.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_spring_cloud_contract_stub_runner) of the doc. And the Assembly file stub.xml is for project using Rest Docs, which I did not use in my project. So there is no json file generated, and no snippets/json path either.